# error: Macro % has illegal name (%define) whenever I run yum

Tags: bash, yum

Whenever I run yum, I get this `error: Macro % has illegal name (%define)` This comes up 4 times.  I have no idea where it's coming from.  I've tried reinstalling yum, didn't work.  This happens with any kind of yum command, like yum clean all, yum search, yum list installed, etc.  Anyone have any idea where this error is so I can correct it?

I googled it and it appears to have a solution at the redhat site but I don't have a subscription to view their solution. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/70201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely that a predefined macro file has a syntax error; something like:

```sh
%define something 1
```

instead of the expected syntax:

```sh
%something 1
```

Look for such a `%define` in the these files:

- ~/.rpmmacros
- /etc/rpm/macros
- /etc/rpm/macros.*

... failing those, perhaps a packaged file was changed:

- /usr/lib/rpm/macros
- /usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/*